# Why does peeking definition not work while going to definition does?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

During debugging a C# program in Visual Studio 2015, when I right click an occurrence of some identities, sometimes choosing peeking its definition will result in no information, while choosing going to its definition will work correctly.

What can cause that difference?

What can I do to make both work?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure (so not posting as an answer), but I think peeking only works if you have the source code for the function. If you don't go do definition goes to the dynamically generated "metadata view" but peek won't do that.

Comment: Do going to definition and peeking both only works if having source code? Then why does one not work while the other does?